# How to fix Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have this error on my latest version of Android Studio:

> Failed to complete Gradle Execution. Cause: The system cannot find the
>   path specified

[image: Failed to complete Gradle Execution. Cause: The system cannot find the path specified]

I cant build and run my project I tried deleting cache file in my `.gradle` folder but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: android studio version?

Comment: u imported or started a new project?

Comment: my android studio version is 3.0.1 and i did not import any project its the project which i made its working fine with no errors when i build and run then suddenly that happens :( can you help me with this?

Comment: Please add your `build.gradle` to the question.

Comment: i tried deleting the cache in the gradle folder then restart the android studio, also i tried to extract new sdk tools. but none these worked for my error i still have the same problem

Comment: Failed to Complete Gradle Execution. Cause: The System cannot find the specified path